Jira Due Dates and Start Dates Reverting to Random Past Dates—Unable to Reset or Change
Here’s a detailed description you can use for your Stack Overflow post:
Problem:
I'm facing an issue where the due dates and start dates for some of my Jira issues are randomly changing to past dates. Whenever I try to update these dates back to the correct values, they immediately revert to those random past dates.
Key points:

The dates are being set to arbitrary past dates, which I did not configure.
When I manually attempt to change the due dates or start dates, the system allows me to make the change, but the values revert back to the same past date as soon as I refresh the page or reopen the ticket.
There are no new automations configured that should be impacting these fields.
I have not changed the workflow or permissions related to the issues in question.
The problem occurs across multiple issues, not just a single ticket.
Other users on my team are experiencing the same behavior with these issues.

I’m an admin for the Jira project and should have full control over the issue fields. This problem only started recently and was not a problem previously. I’m not sure what triggered this behavior, and there haven’t been any recent Jira upgrades or configuration changes (as far as I know).
Has anyone experienced similar issues with due dates or start dates automatically resetting? Could there be something misconfigured in the background, such as a global automation or an issue with field permissions?
Things I've Tried:

Checking if there are any automations running that could be altering the dates – but none are newly created or related to these issues.
Examining workflow rules to see if any transitions are altering dates – no relevant changes were made recently.
Trying different browsers and clearing the cache – the problem persists across platforms.

I was hoping any of these would resolve the issue and let me change the start and due date back to the original dates or revert it back automatically with the fix.

When you looked at the Issue's change history, did you see entries for when you changed the date? Did you also see entries for something else then changing it back?

Does the problem affect only one Project or all Projects? Does the problem only affect one Issue type or all Issue types in that Project / Projects?
